# Segmentation fault in getc()

Tags: c, pointers

I am developing a linked list in C. And I am getting the data from a txt file. But when I try to run the program, it gives me a segmentation fault of getc()
Here's the code,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node{
            char surname[100];
        int number[1o0];
        char name[100];
        struct node *next;
       };
typedef struct node Node;

int main()
{
FILE *ifp;
Node first ,*current;
//current =&first;
int i=0,j=0;
int ch;
char num[100],name[100];

ifp = fopen("tele.txt","r");

 while (ch != EOF)
{       
    while(i<4)
    {
      ch = getc(ifp);
      num[i++] = ch;
    }
    num[i] = '\0'; 
    i=0;
    while(ch !='\n')
    {    
       ch = getc(ifp);
       if(ch != '\t')
         name[j++]=ch;
    }
    name[j] = '\0'; 
    //ch = '\0';

    printf("Number %s\nName %s\n ",num,name);
    j=0;

}

fclose(ifp);
}
```

and the error I am getting while I try to run the program is,

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000003c0ee68dfa in getc () from /lib64/libc.so.6

Kindly guide me in this.
thanks in advance.

---

Comment: It's not related to the segfault, but you should be initializing `ch` before comparing it with `EOF`.  Just by chance it might happen that `ch` would be equal to `EOF` from the beginning and the program would not even enter the `while` loop.

Comment: You need to check the return from **every** `getc()` call for EOF.  As well as checking every function like `fopen()` that can fail.

Comment: How does that even compile with an array size of `1o0`? Don't retype your working code; copy and paste to SO and adjust formatting as needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most likely reason is that it can't open the file.

Check that `ifp` is not NULL immediately after you've called `fopen("tele.txt","r")`. If it is NULL, `errno` will give you more detail of what went wrong (lots of possible reasons, some of which are: the file doesn't exist, you don't have permissions to access it, or you're in the wrong directory.)

There are also several issues around `ch` itself, probably unrelated to the crash:

- `ch` is not initialized, so the `while (ch != EOF)` may or may not be entered [thanks to @Dirk for pointing this out];
- `while(ch !='\n')` is a bit dodgy in that if you encouter `EOF`, you end up in an infinite loop.

Comment: I would add some information about the `ferror` function too.

Comment: @terminus: You seldom need to use `ferror()` if you are coding correctly.

Comment: ... and maybe a word about the fact, that `ch` is not initialized, and thus, its entirely undefined, whether the loop is entered at all...

Comment: @Jonathan that's not true, you can have runtime errors like permission denied.

Comment: @terminus: if the `fopen()` fails, you don't have a valid file pointer to test with `ferror()`.  If the file was opened, you won't get a permission denied later.  On input, you might get a device error or something weird like that, but the return from `getc()` will be EOF.  If you want to distinguish between EOF and some I/O error, then maybe you use `ferror()` (or maybe you use `feof()`).  But generally, most people don't bother.

Comment: `ferror` is useful if failure of any write constitutes failure of an entire save operation. You can simply perform the whole save function and check `ferror` at the end rather than checking each write, simplifying the code a lot. It's quite similar to the way you can use NaNs in floating point code.